# builder.Configuration.GetSection always returning null value, and IOptions<T> always has default properties

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, .net-6.0

I must be missing something out in .NET 6.
This same code worked perfectly fine in previous .NET core. I've found a work arround, but please I need someone to explain to me what's going wrong.

I have a settings class with its JSON representation in my appsettings.json

```
 public class MongoSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }

    public MongoSettings()
    {
        ConnectionString = string.Empty;
        DatabaseName = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

According to what [I read in this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0), I should add the settings this way:

```
    builder.Services.Configure<MongoSettings>(c => builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoSettings"));
```

And I did just that.
I inject this setting as an IOption inside an object I registered in my DI container.
This is the constructor that will receive the settings.

```
public MongoConnection(IOptions<MongoSettings> option)
```

The problem is that the object I receive in the settings always has default values.
My settings are present in the configuration appsettings.json I know that because, when I do the following, I get my settings with its value set to what is in my settings json file:

```
        var mongoSettings = Configuration.GetSection("MongoSettings").Get<MongoSettings>();
```

My question is: Why is the IOptions object I get in my constructor always default ?
This used to work in prior .net versions and in the docs they clearly state that it is the right way.

Comment: Have you gone through the [`Options interfaces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#options-interfaces) remarks. there are some note we should consider as well.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I went through it, what exactly do you want me to see please

Comment: It saying that [Named options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#named-options-support-using-iconfigurenamedoptions) doesn't support in that case you might need to use `IConfigureNamedOptions` another point is the as you want to read updated value other than the defaulf in that scenario I think you might need to use [IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-ioptionssnapshot-to-read-updated-data) This is I wanted to point

Comment: Thankyou I'll try that

Comment: Sure take your time and keep us posted how its going. Feel free to share your further concern as well.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron This didn't work. using IOptionsSnapshot in the constructor instead of IOptions doesn't change anything.

Comment: Could you share your `program.cs` configuration. So that it can be a way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: can you please share also the appsettings.json ? there could be something useful to diagnose the problem, maybe the name of the section is wrong (misstyped) or the structure of the file is messed up